# Creating a hierarchy based on a self referencing table in MS Access '10 using treeview

Tags: vba, ms-access, recursion, treeview, hierarchy

I was trying to follow the instructions on this Microsoft post: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;209891

to create an organization hierarchy chart based on a self referencing table, just like the example. I keep getting an error that the variable is undefined and VBA points to the line "Optional varReportToID As Variant", but the instructions say not to supply anything for this parameter. Is there anything I can do to make the code run? I didn't change the code, I changed the naming on my tables to match the variables listed. I am working in MS Access 2010, but the example is for an older version of MS.

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

'=================Load Event for the Form=======================
'Initiates the routine to fill the TreeView control
'============================================================

Public Sub Form_Load()
    Const strTableQueryName = "Employees"
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strTableQueryName, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    AddBranch rst:=rst, strPointerField:="ReportsTo", strIDField:="EmployeeID",      strTextField:="LastName"
End Sub

'================= AddBranch Sub Procedure ======================
'      Recursive Procedure to add branches to TreeView Control
'Requires:
'   ActiveX Control:  TreeView Control
'              Name:  xTree
'Parameters:
'               rst:  Self-referencing Recordset containing the data
'   strPointerField:  Name of field pointing to parent's primary key
'        strIDField:  Name of parent's primary key field
'      strTextField:  Name of field containing text to be displayed
'=============================================================
Sub AddBranch(rst As Recordset, strPointerField As String, _
          strIDField As String, strTextField As String, _
          Optional varReportToID As Variant)
    On Error GoTo errAddBranch
    Dim nodCurrent As Node, objTree As TreeView
    Dim strCriteria As String, strText As String, strKey As String
    Dim nodParent As Node, bk As String
    Set objTree = Me!xTree.Object
    If IsMissing(varReportToID) Then  ' Root Branch.
        strCriteria = strPointerField & " Is Null"
    Else  ' Search for records pointing to parent.
        strCriteria = BuildCriteria(strPointerField, _
            rst.Fields(strPointerField).Type, "=" & varReportToID)
        Set nodParent = objTree.Nodes("a" & varReportToID)
    End If

    ' Find the first emp to report to the boss node.
    rst.FindFirst strCriteria
    Do Until rst.NoMatch
        ' Create a string with LastName.
        strText = rst(strTextField)
        strKey = "a" & rst(strIDField)
        If Not IsMissing(varReportToID) Then  'add new node to the parent
            Set nodCurrent = objTree.Nodes.Add(nodParent, tvwChild, strKey, strText)
        Else    ' Add new node to the root.
            Set nodCurrent = objTree.Nodes.Add(, , strKey, strText)
        End If
        ' Save your place in the recordset so we can pass by ref for speed.
        bk = rst.Bookmark
        ' Add employees who report to this node.
        AddBranch rst, strPointerField, strIDField, strTextField, rst(strIDField)
        rst.Bookmark = bk     ' Return to last place and continue search.
        rst.FindNext strCriteria   ' Find next employee.
    Loop

'--------------------------Error Trapping --------------------------
    errAddBranch:
        MsgBox "Can't add child:  " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "AddBranch Error:"
        Resume exitAddBranch
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide your code and error.

Comment: Access 2010 Treeview control not working. After Aug 18th update according to this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/3bb15f00-07d8-47a9-85e6-7dfdc1287ca4)